# How can I group by multiple levels of columns in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this

```
progress    Goal    Objective   actions
--------------------------------------
1001237    11723    NULL        NULL
1001237    11723    15094       NULL
1001237    11723    15094       24850
1001237    11723    15095       NULL
1001237    11723    15095       24853
1001237    11724    NULL        NULL
1001237    11724    15097       NULL
1001237    11724    15097       24857
1001237    11725    NULL        NULL
1001237    11726    NULL        NULL
1001237    11726    15098       NULL
1001237    11727    NULL        NULL
1001237    11727    15099       NULL
```

Data hierarchy is like this

- Progress 1:M Goal (Goal cannot be NULL)
- Goal 1:M Objective (Objective can be NULL)
- Objective 1:M Action (Action can be NULL)

I would like to know how to write a query that will group goals, objectives and actions as in the below result set.

```
progress    Goal    Objective   actions
---------------------------------------
1001237     11723   15094       24850
1001237     11723   15095       24853
1001237     11724   15097       24857
1001237     11725   NULL        NULL
1001237     11726   15098       NULL
1001237     11727   15099       NULL
```

Important condition to note is to keep NULL rows if there is only NULL values under a particular category otherwise ignore NULL and keep only the meaningful values.

For ex: NULL was ignored in the objective column under Goal 11723 because it has other valid values but for goal 11725 it was retained.

Similarly NULL in actions column was removed for objective 15097 but not for 15098.

Please advice.

Comment: You get a pass because you're new, but for future reference you should know it's considered very rude here to post an image of data or results instead of text. It makes it harder for us to help you, and makes it less likely you get a good answer, because some people here won't be able to see your images.

Comment: Also.. that's not how sql works. You will have to repeat the progress and goal values for each record in the results.

Comment: Noted. I checked with 'Asking a question' group before posting and no one mentioned about it. But anyway thanks for your advice. Also I understand that SQL doesn't display as I have displayed. I thought it will be easy to understand what I was trying to achieve by showing the report format. Thanks.

Comment: how do I add a table in the question? in text form without affecting the table structure.

Comment: Use `<pre>` tags or indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, not tested

```
select Progress, Goal, Objective ,Action 
from( 
    select Progress, Goal, Objective , Action
      , max(Action) over(partition by Progress, Goal, Objective) ma
      , max(Objective) over(partition by Progress, Goal) mo
      , max(Goal) over(partition by Progress) mg
     from MyTable) t 
where Action is not null 
        or ma is null and 
        (Objective is not null 
            or mo is null and 
            (Goal is not null 
              or mg is null)
        )
```

Comment: It didn't work. Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'group'.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `partition by`. I corrected the answer.

Comment: Works great!! You are a genius!! Thanks so much!!

Comment: You may wish to accept the answer so the others know it's working

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't aware of that. Just did. Thanks.